# Azure port forwarding not working properly

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines

I'm new to Azure Cloud, and all screenshots regarding my question are taken with the Old Azure Portal UI.

**My Issue:**

I forwarded multiple ports

> 7707 UDP/IP (Game Port)
>
> 7708 UDP/IP (Query Port)
>
> 7717 UDP/IP (GameSpy Query Port)
>
> 28852 TCP/IP and UDP (Allows your Server to Connect to the Master
>   Server  Browser)
>
> 8075 TCP/IP (Port set via ListenPort that your WebAdmin will run on)
>
> 20560 UDP/IP (Steam Port)

**What I've done, or want to do:**

I Created a VM in Azure, Ubuntu, installed all files, configured all settings  (?) I followed some online documents to forward the ports. I thought it worked, so i logged into the VM ( i installed a GUI for it so it's acting just like a desktop now. I'm using this VM to run a dedicated KF ( game ) server.

Game Server installed: Check
Game Server running: Check
Game Server showing in Steam: ERROR.
Can join game server OUT of the VM: Check

Here comes the part why i forwarded the ports, those ports are needed to be able to join/see the server inside the game. However, i can only join; server isn't showing.

So am i doing something wrong? I can't find the part related to "EndPoints".

If i do a port check inside the VM, it says ports closed..

i can attach screenshots if you need any.

---

EDIT:

Okay, i just deleted all my resources.

1- I created a new Windows Server
2- Did all basic configuration, [Screenshots Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Wja.jpg)
3- Where to go from here to properly open ports mentioned above ? I need them to be open on the VM itself, inside it. So i can ping the ports, or at least know if they are open/closed from within a browser inside the VM.

Comment: Which doc do you follow to forward the ports? and do you use ARM or ASM model?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT I'm just adding the ports to a Network Security Group. Do i have to do anything else? I also made a load balancer for some reason.

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT I edited my post, check the bottom please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where to go from here to properly open ports mentioned above ? I need
>   them to be open on the VM itself, inside it. So i can ping the ports,
>   or at least know if they are open/closed from within a browser inside
>   the VM.

To open the ports to the virtual machine in the Azure portal, you can create [NSG rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) to filter inbound or outbound traffic on a subnet or VM network interface. For example, I create an inbound rule to allow any source can access the port 7707 with UDP. You can attach the NSG to a subnet or VM interface. The subnet level NSG will take effect on every VM in the same subnet. You also need to open these ports in windows firewall locally on the VM.

[image]

I suppose you have enabled the port forwarding via the NAT rules of the Azure Load Balancer. The target port should match the ports you opened in your NSG.

[image]

To check these ports status, you can run `netstat -anbo` on your Azure VM command prompt as an administrator account. If the game is listening in that port, you also can access it via localhost, so the game is running. Then you can try to access it from outside of VM to verify these ports.

Comment: Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm trying it right now. I already did the parts related to the first picture before i posted this thread, and it wasn't working. I will try again with the LoadBalancer. May i ask why did you put 555 in 2nd screenshot? can i put * ? Or does it have to be a specific port too ?

Comment: I just give an example, it's not a specific port. You only can put a valid value instead of * You also can choose port mapping default or custom.

Comment: It's still not working. I followed step-by-step this guide here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-create-basic-load-balancer-portal Right now ( i deleted all my previous resources and created everything new ) Then i added rules to NSG, NAT Loadbalancer AND inside the VM when i connected via RDP to it. I then go to a port checker website, check a port and it says closed. Any ideas? Also, port 80 says it's open, but anything else is closed.

Comment: Do i also have to create rules in "Load Balancing Rules" other than the port 80 rule inside that guide?

Comment: Yes, you also need to add Load Balancing Rules refer to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal). And what about the output of running `netstat -anbo`  inside the VM.

Comment: This is the output of it: https://pastebin.com/myWUpmEg , i tried with simple https 443 port ( added it everywhere ) and it still shows as closed.

Comment: And i can't add the ports in both, NAT and Balancing rules. it says the rule already exists and they must be unique. Also, the link you gave me is for NAT Rules.

Comment: Could you make sure the service already start on the VM?  Is there a server running on the port when you verify the port.

Comment: isn't 443 for https ? Weird thing is that i can browse/download files normally over the internet INSIDE the VM. How do i check if it's running properly ? I'm running this netstat -ant|findstr 443 and this is the output: https://pastebin.com/T2TSmevQ , however, if i run the same command on, let's say, 7707 - it doesn't give anything, just empty output.

Comment: Wait, i "Think" it's working now. Give me some time to test it and i'll report back!

Comment: It's working! Thankyou so much. That guide should be pinned somewhere for importance! If i encounter anything else i'll tell you. have a good day!

Comment: Glad to hear that this helps.:)